# DRF(django-rest-framework) and TokenAuthentication, how to fill json field automatically based Token?

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, token

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
}
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_postwriter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'related_postwriter')

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'created_date', 'author', 'text', 'image')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['author'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super(PostSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='related_postwriter')
    text = models.TextField(blank = False)
    image = models.ImageField(null = False, blank = False, upload_to='images')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now
        )

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.text
```

**views.py**

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

I had to make this RESTful api for json request and json response.
When i use this RESTful api for Android application, I learned that i login and get Token from RESTful api, and then that Token is used to post data to RESTful api through Header.

As postman capture,

[image]

I must fill "author":"number" on Body. I think this number means that user's registering order on my RESTful api. From above capture, that author is first user of my RESTful api.

If i made author field empty, it returned

```
{
  "author": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}
```

1. How can i fill "author" part automatically using Token (or other way not using Token)?
2. How can i get json response `"author":"some alphabet name readable"`, not `"author":"1 or 2 like number"` as capture. I want form like `"author":"stackoverflowman"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for you first question, you should add in `PostViewSet` this function:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
     serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

for your second question, you should call the `UserSerializer` from `PostSerializer`:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'created_date', 'author', 'text', 'image')
```

**EDIT**

if you only want one field, you can declare a field with source:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'created_date', 'author', 'text', 'image')
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for one more question, As your answer, it returns     `"author": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "ghdalsrn",
      "email": "",
      "related_postwriter": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]` It works very well, but when i want just one field to be returned, yes, `"username"` field, what should i do?